# Implement cached Livescore

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, request

I have been implementing a livescore for my app by getting requests from an API. The problem is that at the moment it's making requests every 5 seconds for updating the score. This seems like a lot of API calls.

The  livescore contain 5 leagues, so there it is only 3 days a week and a specific time where there is livescores available, so often it is just a waste of API calls.

How could i improve this, for making as few Calls as possible. Could i maybe implement, some kind of cached.

Comment: Do you constantly show the livescores or only when they are requested?

Comment: i show them constantly

Comment: Your task is a bit hard to understand then. You basically have an iOS app that has a UIView that's constantly showing the highscores no matter where you are at the view hierarchy of the app? If that's the case, perhaps it would be better to use socket connection instead of sending a ton of API calls?

Comment: Yes basically i have a UIViewController with an UITableView which contain livescores and updates every 5 seconds. This will send a ton of connections. Do you still recommend socket connection?

Comment: Whether or not to use the socket connection really depends. If you have the time and open for the challenge, then you should go for it. Of course you can take an easy path and add a refresh button to your score boards, so users would refresh the scores whenever they feel like it. Other than this solution, if you need to keep the score boards updated all the time anytime, the only possible option is to use socket. If there's no strict rule forbidding you from showing a bit outdated information, you could increase the interval between requests and send them, say, once a twenty-thirty seconds.